# Lambda expression with && python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, dataset, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use a lambda expression to be able to extract date with two conditions.
when I write this it works

```html
newdf.loc[lambda newdf: newdf['yearly_premium'] > 2784, :]
```

but when I add another condition it doesnt :/

```html
newdf.loc[lambda newdf: newdf['yearly_premium'] > 2784 and newdf['Total_Claim_Amount'] < 1021.654, :]
```

can someone tell me how can I adjust it? thank you guys

Comment: Why are you using a lambda expression here at all? It's totally pointless

Comment: In any case, "it doesn't work" isn't an adequate problem description. How did it not work *exactly*? For questions like this, you must provide a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, post the full error message inlcuding the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a `lambda` function to `DataFrame.loc`, the expression must evaluate to a boolean array. Multiple conditions in a single expression can be specified using boolean operators so that the evaluation of the entire expression is also a boolean array, e.g.:

```python
lambda newdf: (newdf['yearly_premium'] > 2784) & (newdf['Total_Claim_Amount'] < 1021.654)
```

Note that each condition is wrapped in parentheses. This is because the default Python evaluation order would otherwise not yield the result that you expect.

**Example**

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [3, 4, 5]})
newdf = df.loc[lambda df: (df['x'] > 1) & (df['y'] < 5)]

print(df)
print(newdf)
```

**Output**

```python
   x  y
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5

   x  y
1  2  4
```

**Note about using `lambda`**

It's worth noting that a `lambda` function isn't required in this particular use case. In the previous example, the same result can be achieved directly using labels, e.g.:

```python
newdf = df.loc[(df['x'] > 1) & (df['y'] < 5)]
```

See [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) for additional documentation.

Comment: You should probably note... a lambda expression is really pointless here

Comment: Added a note about using `lambda`.